# from Optional to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this type defined

```
export type Optional<T> = T | null | undefined;
```

and

```
let id: Optional<Hostel> = ids[0];
```

and

```
await this.repository.getHostelAsync(id);
```

but I have this error:

```
 Argument of type 'Optional<Hostel>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Hostel'.
```

and I don't know how to convert from `Optional<Hostel> to Hostel`

Comment: do an `if` condition to check for not null and then assign

Comment: You probably need to check, something like `if(id) { await this.repository.getHostelAsync(id); } else { /* what if id is null, then what , up to you */ }`